# Use Rouches' Theorem to show an entire function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help me find proof for this using Rouche's Theorem.

$$Let\; f\; be\; entire\; and\; let\; |f(z)|\leq5\sqrt{|z|}\;for \;all \;|z|\geq1.\;\; Prove\; that\; f\; is\; constant.$$

This problem is from Marsden Hoffmann section 6.2. The main theorems of that section are "The Principle of Argument" , "Rouche's Theorem", and "The One-to-One Theorem".

I am able to prove this using Cauchy's Inequality, but my professor claimed it is possible to show it with Rouche's Theorem. He told me, "Consider a circle of radius $R$... Let $R\rightarrow \infty$". I thought Rouche's Theorem only gave information about the number of zeros and poles the function has. I don't see how it would apply here.

Can anyone think of a proof involving "The Principle of Argument" , "Rouche's Theorem", or "The One-to-One Theorem"? Thank you!

Comment: What about $f(z) = 5\sqrt{\sqrt{|z|}}$?

Comment: I dont see how this is an entire function @SalmonKiller

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam $f$ as a function of $z$?

Comment: @SalmonKiller It needs to be entire. That's what I am saying

Answer (score 0):

The proof does not use Rouché's theorem. It uses Cauchy's formula and follows closely the proof of Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware of the proof using Cauchy's formula. Are you sure it isn't possible to show it another way?

Comment: There may be other methods I am not aware of, but most surely are more involved. Rouche's Theorem and the Argument principle are about the location of zeroes of a function.